# Displaying List with large amount of data in each item

Tags: website-design, lists

I have a list of Schedule items to display.  Each List item has a Name a schedule period and then a whole bunch of times, places and things that are scheduled.   The amount times, places and things are virtually unlimited. Here is a general layout

```
Name   |  Date to Date
------------------------
Some help text

List of times  |  List of Places | List of things

List of times  |  List of Places | List of things

List of times  |  List of Places | List of things
```

The list of Times, places and things can be long.  I will have multiple schedules listed on a page.  Right now the page looks fairly busy.  Normally I would use a table but as you can see each schedule has a lot of data.

Can anyone suggest a nice way to display a list such as this?  I am using jQuery as my JavaScript framework.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Hipmunk.com.  They have a nice way of showing flights with times costs in a very user friendly way.  Just search for an example flight and you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to think what part of that data (times, places, things) is really useful to the user. Can you somehow sort it by relevance and show the more relevant ones and offer the rest by 'click for more' or something similar.

This might sound difficult or maybe even imposible, but when you look at it from the users perspective... if you show enormous amounts of data, how is that useful to the user? It probably isn't so you need to filter the amount of data down by some relevan criteria.

Comment: Good idea, I think Name and Date range will be enough.  I will use show more to display Times, Places and Things.